Improving Gravatar avatar management? –> new Gravatar Quick Editor Feature
Enhancement suggestion:
Gravatar has a new feature, that would simplify the way how Stackoverflow users could update their avatars via Gravatar.
It’s easy to implement, and could be easily integrated via link in this profile modal:

The experience is similar to using a familiar payment service provider like PayPal or Stripe. Users click the link, authenticate their account in a popup, manage their profile, and then get redirected back to the platform.
The new Quick Editor allows users to directly edit and manage their Gravatar profiles within third-party platforms.
You can take a look at the feature here: Edit Gravatar Everywhere – The Quick Editor  and in the GitHub library

SE hasn't supported gravatar in years. Existing ones would work, but new ones would not. As such this seems somewhat moot

Full disclosure, Thomas from Automattic here. This is a new Gravatar feature we are just launching. Please check the documentation.
Might be a feature that is not needed, or useful, certainly no spam though.

They're valid links. I took a look. I did need to google OP's name to work out that they're a Automattic employee.

@W.O. In theory you could swap it on gravatar's end and bypass that if you had it set up previously.

SE's changed a lot since the early days - imgur, openid and gravatar were integral part of the early platform and are hardly used or sunset as the years went on. The current preferred avatar system is built around the new image hosting setup that replaced imgur (and was imgur). Most gravatars that're still in use are 'old' ones from years ago. I'm not exactly sure when the change happened but it was probably before 2021
I'd guess there's some old documentation in your company that says SE uses it (since I don't see any other accounts) - which might need to be documented, but I suspect it'll eventually be moot.
I'm not staff (so take anything I say with a slight pinch of salt) but there's probably not enough active development on that feature for the change to be needed.
